# Tableau : Filter Value

Tags: tableau-api

I have below data for a filter.

[image: Filter Data Value]

But need some rollup and create new filter list values as
Online (includes App, Desktop and Mobile) and 
Offline (includes Kiosk and Pos)

[image: Required Filter Data Value]

Any Suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a parameter (i.e., "PSource") with all of the values that you want to have (original plus groups) and make sure it is shown on your worksheet or dashboard. Create a calculated field (i.e., "CSource") where "Source" is the assumed name of the field in your data that includes your original values:

```
   CASE [PSource Parameter]
       WHEN "Online (All)" THEN IIF(FIND("App/Desktop Browser/Mobile Browser",[Source])>0,"T","F")
       WHEN "Offline (All)" THEN IIF(FIND("Kiosk/Pos",[Source])>0,"T","F")
       WHEN "App" THEN IIF([Source]="App","T","F")
       WHEN "Desktop Browser" THEN IIF([Source]="Desktop Browser","T","F")
       WHEN "Mobile Browser" THEN IIF([Source]="Mobile Browser","T","F")
       WHEN "Kiosk" THEN IIF([Source]="Kiosk","T","F")
       WHEN "Pos" THEN IIF([Source]="Pos","T","F")
   END
```

Drop CSource onto the Filters shelf and select the "T" value.